# find string from a directory and replace it using batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, findstr

I want to find string e.g. "date" from my files of a folder which contains multiple ".c" and ".h" files in it and replace it with "date 24-April-2018" using batch file. what should do? Please see below code. I want to do the same but not for one file Input.txt , I want to do for multiple files with extensions of a folder

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=@date"
set "replace=@date 24-apr-2018"

set "textFile=Input.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Ever looked into the [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)? By the way, one `setlocal` command is enough, so remove the first one...

Comment: That's because you're specifically assigning `textfile` to a single file! You could nest your current `for /f` loop inside a `for` loop which outputs the files your require, e.g. `for %%x in (*.c *.h) do (<your existing for loop with %textfile% replaced with %%x>))>"%newfile%"`

Comment: This powershell one liner replaces all `date` with `date ` and current date attached in all .c and .h in current folder. `sls -pattern "date" -path *.c,*.h |select -unique -expand path|%{(gc $_ ) -replace "\bdate\b","$1 $(get-date -f 'dd-MMM-yyyy')" |sc $_".bak"}` Appends .bak to the new file name.

Comment: But I don't want create another file and then delete older file. I want to find and replace string within the same file.This was the example code but this didn't work for me

Comment: Every edit of a file implies a read,change and write back. I appended  the `.bak` for testing purposes. I you find the result ok simply remove that appending. And there is no ned to crosspost to [su]